# Cypress Testing - Using If Logic To Find "Apply Now" In Vacancies To Test "Apply Now" Work Flow

Tags: typescript, cypress

**Background:**

Sometimes, the user has already applied to the job, from which the "Apply Now" button will not be visible, but instead, a success message telling them they've already applied.

**Use Case:**

I would like to map through the listings on a job board, until I see a job listing with the "Apply Now" logic, as I need to test the flow for logged in users.

When clicking the first "Apply Now", I would like to stop looking for other job listings the user can apply to.

I believe this requires some `if/else` logic, but I am unsure how to do this, with [Cypress talking unfavourably about it](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing).

**Code:**

```
describe("Candidate Applications", () => {
  // 1. Login as a candidate
  beforeEach(() => cy.loginByCognito(Cypress.env("candidate_username"), Cypress.env("candidate_password")));

  it("passes", () => {
    // 2. Go to the first job listing
    cy.visit(TEACHING_JOBS);
    const arrayOfListings = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];

    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfListings.length; i++) {
      cy.get(`[datacy="displayTitle"] `).eq(i).click();
      cy.wait(2000);

      // If the applicationTop does not contain "Apply Now", use cy.go("back") to go back to the previous page

      cy.get("body").then(body => {
        if (body.find('[datacy="applyNow"]').length > 0) {
            // 3. Apply to the vacancy
            cy.get(`[datacy="applyNow"]`).first().click();
            ...

            break;

        } else {
          cy.go("back");
        }
      });
    }
   });
});
```

**Errors:**

1. All the text is underlined yellow, with the error `Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) 'cy', 'cy', 'cy', 'cy', 'cy', 'cy', 'cy', 'cy', 'cy'.`
2. Adding `break` introduced the error `Jump target cannot cross function boundary` with Cypress gui saying `Module parse failed: Unsyntactic break (37:20)`

Comment: Gleb says [you are making life hard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0d3SKQ-9WJI).

Comment: I've used this for finding the button, but if the button does not exist, I want to go back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using `.each()`, as recommended by Shankar, I progressed to complete this test.

**The requirements where:**

1. To iterate through the job listings until an Apply Now Button is found
2. To stop the loop when the Apply Now Button is found
3. To complete the job application work flow when the Apply Now Button is found

**The code solution is:**

```
  it("the candidate can apply to a job listing", () => {
    // Go to the Job Board
    cy.visit(TEACHING_JOBS);
    // Ensure the title is visible of the job board page
    cy.contains("Education Vacancies").should("be.visible");
    // Use shouldStop to stop the loop upon a successfull application
    let shouldStop = false;
    // Look for the displayTitle class and loop through each one
    cy.get("body")
      .find("[datacy='displayTitle']")
      .each((displayTitle, i) => {
        // If shouldStop is true, then stop the loop
        cy.then(() => {
          if (shouldStop) {
            return;
          }
          // Click on the displayTitle and use i to get the correct index - This helps iterate through each job listing
          cy.get('[datacy="displayTitle"]').eq(i).click();
          cy.wait(3000);
          cy.get("body").then(body => {
            // If Cypress finds the applyNow button, then click it and apply to the job
            if (body.find('[datacy="applyNow"]').length > 0) {
              //When the applyNow button has been found:
              // - set shouldStop to true to stop the loop
              // - click on the applyNow button and start the application until completion
              shouldStop = true;
              // Complete the application form logic
              cy.get('[datacy="applyNow"]').first().click();
              cy.get(`[datacy="salaryConfirmationApplication"]`).click();
              cy.contains("I am happy with the salary").click();
              cy.get(`[datacy="startDateApplication"]`).click();
              cy.contains("I can start on the requested start date").click();
              cy.get(`[datacy="contactEmployerApplication"]`).click();
              cy.contains("Please contact the employer").click();
              cy.get(`[datacy="applyToVacancy"]`).click();
              cy.get('.MuiAlert-message').should('be.visible');
            } else {
              // If the applyNow button is not found, then go back to the job board and click on the next job listing
              cy.go("back");
            }
          });
        });
      });
  });
```

Comment: Gleb explains how to stop a `cy.each()` loop here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G4xs9_cAm2c&ab_channel=glebbahmutov

Answer (score 3):

Dont do `const arrayOfListings = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];` to drive a for loop.

Instead use the proper Cypress command

```js
cy.get('[datacy="displayTitle"]').each(($el, i) => {
  $el.click()
  ...
})
```

This should if not fix move you forward.